# Aggregation on terms and not on whole field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with products (ES 6.3), where some of the product names look like this `Tomato`, `Tomatosoup`, `Tomatojuice` etc. What I'm trying to achieve, is when I query for example by the term `Toma`, to get an aggregation of the best matching terms instead of the whole product names.

To achieve this, I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "name": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "custom-ngram" // Defined in the mapping
    "search-analyzer": "standard",
    "fields": {
      "suggestion": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my query looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":{
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "tom",
          "fields": ["name^3", "description"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "suggestions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.suggestion",
        "include": "tom.*", 
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Indeed this works and gives me back what I need but I have two concerns:

1. The usage of `fielddata` which is not encouraged based on the ES docs
2. The usage of the `includes` directive to actually filter the aggregation buckets

Is this the right way to go on solving this issue or the approach is completely wrong? Is there any best practice for this problem?

Comment: What you describe and the query you are using look like the opposite. You say you need `an aggregation of the best matching terms instead of the whole product names` but your aggregation is being performed on the product names and not the ngrams you are searching on: `"field": "name.suggestion"`. Or I don't understand what you need...

Comment: The problem is that If I aggregate on `name` I will get back buckets with ngrams. What I want is to get aggregations on `Tomato`, `Tomatosoup ` and `Tomatojuice`.

Comment: Using fielddata is not the end of the world, it's just more memory usage. One needs to be a bit careful with it, but using it doesn't mean your cluster will die. Why don't you define another sub-field which will be a `keyword` and aggregate on that? I may be missing something...

Comment: That was what my first though in order to avoid `fielddata`. Having a `keyword` and doing the aggregation on that. But because the keyword is not `tokenized`, the aggregation works on full product names. And because each product name is different (e.g. `Tomatosoup 500ml`, `Tomatosoup 1liter`) I get one bucket for each product.

Comment: Then the solution you have now is the one.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks